# MySQL can distinguish NULL and ""(null character string)

Tags: mysql, validation

I set default value in a field NOT NULL.
The sql is as follows.

```
insert into table_name () values ()
```

I expected this sql should be rejected by MySQL as a field restricts NULL.
But, the field had a value ""(null character string).

Then, I tried another sql.

```
insert into table_name (name) values (NULL)
```

As this sql was rejected, no value was inserted.

MySQL seems to distinguish NULL and "". Do I have to avoid first sql such as "values ()"?

Comment: If you don't need a value then keep the NOT NULL, if you do then you need to enter one in the INSERT statement or set a default value. One or the other is required or it will return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to set default value in a field that is set as NOT NULL?

**YES** if you are doing an `INSERT` where in you will not set any values to the NOT NULL columns

and

**NO** not needed anymore, if you are providing a value on the columns that are NOT NULL on `INSERT`.

You can refer to this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

Answer (score 1):

For a good practice always make the column as not null and set a default value whenever you create a table.

At insert time if you do not provide a value, the column will then be assigned the default value.